# Why the product of two pseudotensor would be a tensor?

Tags: tensor-calculus, parity

I’m reading The Classical Theory of Fields by landau, and I’m quite confused about pseudotensor in the book, which indicates that the product of two pseudotensor would be a tensor. A example is that $e^{ijkl} e^{prst}$ would be a tensor. As mensioned before, the $e^{ijkl}$ wouldn’t change it’s component while a tensor will when coordinate inverses. So why the product would change?